# Google drive spreadsheet and calendar invite guest

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

Okay,  first of all, what I'm trying to do is updating Google sheet and calendar simultaneously. So, let say if there's an update to your spreadsheet there will also be an update to the calendar. However, here's all the things that I failed to do.

1. If there's changes in the calendar , there will be no changes in the   spreadsheet
2. I'm unable to find code to invite guest to the calendar. So far , all i know is that i need to to use " attendee[] " but I'm unable to find example to show me on how its done. I've found some java code but its different if I'm not mistaken.

So, these will be the order for the spreadsheet

Date    Title   Start Time  End Time    Location    Description Guest   EventID

This one is the code on the google sheets.

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Export Events",
    functionName : "exportEvents"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions ", entries);
};


function exportEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;  
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "email"; // calenderID
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i in data) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; 
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[0]); 
    var title = row[1];           
    var tstart = new Date(row[2]);
    tstart.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstart.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstart.setYear(date.getYear());
    tstart.setMinutes( tstart.getMinutes() + 6)
    var tstop = new Date(row[3]);
    tstop.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstop.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstop.setYear(date.getYear());
    tstop.setMinutes(tstop.getMinutes() + 6)
    var loc = row[4];
    var desc = row[5];
    var guest = row[6]
    var id = row[7];              
   
  
    
    try 
    {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
      event.deleteEventSeries();
      row[7] = '';    
    }
    catch (e) {
      
    }
    
    var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, new Date(tstart), new Date(tstop), {description:desc,location:loc}).getId();
    row[7] = newEvent;  
    debugger;
    
   }

  range.setValues(data);
}
```

If possible , I would some guidance on this , since I'm stuck.

Comment: After some more research , i found out that i need to use these code. 
var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
    event.addGuest(guest);
but it didnt work , it says action not allowed

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376942/adding-guests-to-calendar-event and also this brilliant one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788897/create-google-calendar-events-from-spreadsheet-but-prevent-duplicates/15790894#15790894

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, if you want to create a new event for each new entry in spread sheet you could use [Calender](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar) class and create an event.

If you want to edit an already created event and add new guests you could use [CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#addGuest(String)) class and add guests.

Hope that helps!