# Google Scripts - Add guests to a calendar event from a google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I've created a google form, which goes to a google sheet from which calendar entries are automatically created.  However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to invite a guest from my sheet.  I've thoroughly googled it and found some similar solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936870/google-drive-spreadsheet-and-calendar-invite-guest) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376942/adding-guests-to-calendar-event), but their code is quite different from mine so I can't figure out how apply it to my code.

This is my latest attempt:

```
//insert your google calendar ID
var calendarId = "CALENDARID";

//index (starting from 1) of each column in the sheet
var titleIndex = 4;
var descriptionIndex = 7;
var startDateIndex = 5;
var endDateIndex = 6;
var googleCalendarIndex = 10;
var locationIndex = 8;
var mainGuestIndex = 2; 

/*
find the row where the Google Calendar Event ID is blank or null
The data of this row will be used to create a new calendar event
*/
function findRow( sheet )
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var values = dataRange.getValues();

    for ( var loopCounter = 0;
          loopCounter < values.length;
          loopCounter++ )
    {
        if ( values[ loopCounter ][ googleCalendarIndex - 1 ] == "" ||
             values[ loopCounter ][ googleCalendarIndex - 1 ] == null )
             newEvent( i + 1 );
    } 
};

/* 
get the data of the new row by calling getSheetData() and 
create a new Calendar event by calling submitToGoogleCalendar()
*/

function newEvent( row )
{ 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var eventId = submitToGoogleCalendar(getSheetData(sheet,row),null)

    if ( eventId != null ) 
        sheet.getRange( row,
                        googleCalendarIndex,
                        1,
                        1 ).setValue( eventId );
};

/* 
Store the data of a row in an Array
*/

function getSheetData(sheet,row)
{
    var data = new Array();

    data.title = sheet.getRange( row,
                                 titleIndex,
                                 1,
                                 1 ).getValue();

    data.description = sheet.getRange( row,
                                       descriptionIndex,
                                       1,
                                       1 ).getValue();

    data.startDate = sheet.getRange( row,
                                     startDateIndex,
                                     1,
                                     1 ).getValue();

    data.endDate = sheet.getRange( row,
                                   endDateIndex,
                                   1,
                                   1 ).getValue();

    data.location = sheet.getRange( row,
                                    locationIndex,
                                    1,
                                    1 ).getValue();

    data.mainGuest = sheet.getRange( row,
                                     mainGuestIndex,
                                     1,
                                     1 ).getValue(); 

    return data;
};

/* 
if a cell is edited in the sheet, get all the data of the corresponding row and 
create a new calendar event (after deleting the old event) by calling submitToGoogleCalendar() 
*/

function dataChanged( event )
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var row = event.range.getRow();

    var eventId = sheet.getRange( row,
                                  googleCalendarIndex,
                                  1,
                                  1 ).getValue();

    var eventId = submitToGoogleCalendar( getSheetData( sheet,
                                                        row),
                                          eventId );

    if ( eventId != null )
        sheet.getRange( row,
                        googleCalendarIndex,
                        1,
                        1 ).setValue( eventId );
};

/* 
This function creates an event in the Google Calendar and returns the calendar event ID 
which is stored in the last column of the sheet 
*/

function submitToGoogleCalendar( sheetData,
                                 eventId )
{
    // some simple validations ;-)
    if ( sheetData.title == "" ||
         sheetData.startDate == "" ||
         sheetData.startDate == null )
        return null;

    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById( calendarId );
    var start = new Date( sheetData.startDate );
    var end = new Date( sheetData.endDate );

    // some simple date validations
    if ( start > end )
        return null;

    var event = null;

    //if eventId is null (when called by newEvent()) create a new calendar event
    if ( eventId == null )
    {
        event = cal.createEvent( sheetData.title,
                                 start,
                                 end,
                                 { 
                                     description : sheetData.description,
                                     location    : sheetData.location,
                                 } ).addGuest( sheetData.mainGuest );

        return event.getId(); 
    }

    /*
    else if the eventid is not null (when called by dataChanged()), delete the calendar event 
    and create a new event with the modified data by calling this function again
    */

    else
    {
        event = cal.getEventSeriesById( eventId );
        event.deleteEventSeries();
        return submitToGoogleCalendar( sheetData,
                                       null );
    }

    return event.getId();
};
```

However, when I run this it makes an event, but still no guest shows up in the calendar event.  From [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#addguestemail) I know I need to use `.addGuest(email)`, and it seems like it should go in my `submitToGoogleCalendar` function as that's where all the other info in the event is, but no luck so far.  I've also tried adding `event.addGuest(sheetData.mainGuest);` instead of tacking it on to the event of the event variable, but that didn't work either.

How can I add this without totally rewriting my script? Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Try to use the [`addGuest(email)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#addGuest(String)) parameter and with a valid email address. eg. `addGuest(xyz@email.com)` and check it it works. Because it is the only way to add guest by using the Apps Script. Just check this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) to know how to use the Calendar in Apps Script. Also, check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40842714), to know how the user add guest to his code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include it as an advanced option with location. sendInvites is the fourth option with a value of either true or false to email the guests.

[Class Calendar: Create Event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date))

```js
event = cal.createEvent( sheetData.title,
                                 start,
                                 end,
                                 { 
                                     description : sheetData.description,
                                     location    : sheetData.location,
                                     guests      : sheetData.mainGuest,
                                     sendInvites : true
                                 } );
```